# How to pass the text/Value of an Html element from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to access the value of button in controller and then pass it to the view as well.
       But the value of "str" passed from view to controller is null.

```
Index.chtml

@{
     var str = "Shoes";
}

<a href="~/Home/Products_By_Category/@str" target="_parent">
                <input type="button" value="Shoes" class="btn"/>
      </a>
```

/////////////////////////

```
<pre lang="c#">

     public ActionResult Products_By_Category(string s)
     {
           ViewBag.category = s;
           return View();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the same name s for your input also.
Use ViewBag.category in the client side. Since ViewBag is a dynamic entity.
Are you using form submit in which case MVC will automatically fill the value of the input for you.

Comment: No i'm not using form tag. Actually I want to use the view variable in controller. ViewBag.category is just an example of accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm using

Index.cshtml

```
    @{
      var str="Shoes";
}

<form action="~/Home/Products_By_Category/@str" method="post">

      <input type="submit" value="Shoes" class="btn"/>

</form>
```

/////////////

```
public ActionResult Products_By_Category(string s)
{
       var context = new Shoe_StoreDBEntities();
       var q = from p in context.Products
            join c in context.Categories on p.CategoryId equals c.Id
            where c.Name.Equals(s)
            select new { p, c };
}
```

but still the value in "s" is still null

Answer (score 0):

First. The controller passes data to the view. There is no other way around. It's because the basic nature of a webapplication.
Basically: Request -> controller -> select and render a view.
The view itself is not a known concept in the client browser. That is simple html/css/js.
Your view should looks like this:

```
@{
  var str = "Shoes";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Products_By_Category"))
{
  <input type="submit" name="s" id="s" value="@(str)"/>
}
```

Some note:
1) If you use a variable inside an html element attribute you have to bracket it.
2) You should use the builtin html helper whenever it's possible (beginform)
3) This example only work if you click the submit button to postback the data. If there is other submit button or initiate the postback from js, the button data is not included into the formdata. You should use a hidden field to store the str value and not dependent from the label of the button:

```
@{
  var str = "Shoes";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Products_By_Category"))
{
  <input type="hidden" id="s" name="s" value="@(str)"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Do postback"/>
}
```

Comment: can built-in helper of html (beginform) be used more than one times in one view?

Comment: Of course. But don't forget they just helpers. They do as you write the code. You have to keep the rules of html. So can't nest a form inside a form. But you can use any number of form tag in a view. (Not like asp.net webforms)